# Mathematica suspends long calculation

Tags: interruption

I have the following weird problem: I am performing some monte carlo simulations through a simple do loop, where each round takes about 1-5 minutes. I was running 1000 or so overnight, and realized that *Mathematica* sometimes seems to be suspended for hours. On the next morning, I saw the calculation was suspended at some point during the night. Bizarrely, once I simply bring the notebook into the foreground, the computation resumed immediately. So I assume that windows is suspending the calculation somehow. However, the computer itself is definitely not suspended; I ran some other things to rule this out. I can reproduce the problem with several notebooks running in parallel - but I noticed no pattern. The different notebooks do not suspend at the same time (I notice the time by writing some files on disk each round in the loop), and sometimes do not suspend at all. Did anyone ever encounter such problem?

Versions are: *Mathematica* 10.2 or 10.3, Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit, used two different machines ( I think I also got this on a third Win 10 machine but will recheck)

Comment: At the moment, there is not enough info / too much ambiguity to pin down the issue,  which may or may not have a *Mathematica* cause.  What exactly do you mean by "suspend"...  optimally,  you should supply small code samples to reproduce the problem. It sounds to me that your notebook goes to sleep at some point, which would be an Windows thing,  but again,  not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will turn out to be purely a Windows problem. It might or might not be tied to a particular version. I would search Google for something along the lines of

windows 7 suspends application overnight

In doing that search I would be noticing if some word other than "suspending" might be commonly used to indicate such a situation. If you find another word, you could substitute it for "suspending" in your Google search query. I would keep the word "overnight" since it is going to pick up people who let things run for long periods of time.